# Extract pattern from a string

Tags: bash

In bash script, what is the easy way to extract a text pattern from a string?

For example, I want to extract `X` followed by 2 digits in the end of the string?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Show us something broken, we'll tell you how to fix it.

Comment: learn sed and regular expressions.

Comment: I liked the `egrep` solution presented in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568859/how-to-extract-text-from-a-string-using-sed

Answer (score 30):

There's a nifty `=~` regex operator when you use [double square brackets](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031). Captured groups are made available in the `$BASH_REMATCH` array.

```
if [[ $STRING =~ (X[0-9]{2})$ ]]; then
    echo "matched part is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Comment: By far the easiest solution !!! I just passed 2 hours to understand how to use Pattern Expansion, but it seems a little bit weird !!! so thank you ;)

Answer (score 17):

Lets take your input as

**Input.txt**

```
ASD123
GHG11D3456
FFSD11dfGH
FF87SD54HJ
```

And the pattern I want to find is **"SD[digit][digit]"**

**Code**

> grep -o 'SD[0-9][0-9]' Input.txt

**Output**

```
SD12
SD11
SD54
```

And if you want to use this in script...then you can assign the above code in a variable/array... that's according to your need.

Comment: **+1** - I forgot about `grep -o`.  Good suggestion, though per the OP's question I suspect it would be good to include: `grep -o 'X[0-9][0-9]$' input.txt`

Comment: I had to use -e option also . i was using grep with variable as input so I had to do echo $my_var | grep -oe "pattern"

Answer (score 8):

```
$ foo="abcX23"
$ echo "$(echo "$foo" | sed 's/.*\(X[0-9][0-9]\)$/\1/')"
X23
```

or

```
if [[ "$foo" =~ X[0-9][0-9]$ ]]; then
  echo "${foo:$((${#foo}-3))}"
fi
```

Comment: A downvote with no comment?  How is my answer false or misleading?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use parameter expansion:

```
V="abcX23"
PREFIX=${V%%X[0-9][0-9]} # abc
SUFFIX=${V:${#PREFIX}}   # X23
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to extract the host port from this string:
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = guestssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = , host port = 2222, guest ip = , guest port = 22

That string is obtained by using: vboxmanage showvminfo Mojave | grep 'host port', I mean is filtered and I need to extract whatever number be in the host port; in this case is 2222 but it can be different.

Comment: This was originally a question and I got the solution: 

if [[ "$(vboxmanage showvminfo Mojave | grep 'host port')" =~ (host\ port\ =\ [0-9]+) ]]; then
    echo "Port is '${BASH_REMATCH[1]/host\ port\ =\ /}'"
fi