# How to extract text from a string using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

My example string is as follows:

```
This is 02G05 a test string 20-Jul-2012
```

Now from the above string I want to extract `02G05`. For that I tried the following regex with sed

```
$ echo "This is 02G05 a test string 20-Jul-2012" | sed -n '/\d+G\d+/p'
```

But the above command prints nothing and the reason I believe is it is not able to match anything against the pattern I supplied to sed.

So, my question is what am I doing wrong here and how to correct it.

When I try the above string and pattern with python I get my result

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+G\d+',st)
['02G05']
>>>
```

Comment: Python is definitely not `sed`. Their regex flavors are quite different.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The pattern `\d` might not be supported by your `sed`. Try `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead.

To only print the actual match (not the entire matching line), use a substitution.

```
sed -n 's/.*\([0-9][0-9]*G[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

The parentheses *capture* the text they match into a *back reference.* Here, the first (and only) parentheses capture the string we want to keep, and we replace the entire line with just the captured string `\1`, and print the resulting line. (The `p` option says to print the resulting line after performing a successful substitution, and the `-n` option prevents `sed` from performing its normal printing of every other line.)

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. But I have a question why `.*` is necessary with your regex because when I try `sed  -n 's/\([0-9]\+G[0-9]\+\)/\1/p'` it just prints the entire line.

Comment: That's why, isn't it? Replace whatever comes before and after the match with norhing, then print the whole line.

Comment: @tripleee This only prints `2G05` not `02G05`. The expression that works is `'s/.*\([0-9][0-9]G[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: That hard-codes it to exactly two digits. Something like `sed -n 's/\(.*[^0-9]\)\?\([0-9][0-9]*G[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\2/p'` would be more general. (I assume your `sed` supports `\?` for zero or one occurrence.)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898886/874188 for how to replace various other common Perl escapes like `\w`, `\s`, etc.

Comment: @tripleee your "to only print the actual match...." was the pointer i needed for what i was trying to do

Comment: @tripleee what do you want to show with `sed -n 's/\(.*[^0-9]\)\?\([0-9][0-9]*G[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\2/p'`? This is confusing, `\1`  is not used.

Comment: Why is it confusing? I discard whatever the first group matches. The `\?` makes it optional (so it could be empty) but if there is anything before the number, we remove it.

Answer (score 137):

How about using `grep -E`?

```
echo "This is 02G05 a test string 20-Jul-2012" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+G[0-9]+'
```

Comment: +1 This is simpler, and will also correctly handle the case of multiple matches on the same line. A complex `sed` script could be devised for that case, but why bother?

Comment: `egrep` uses extended regexp, `sed` and `grep` uses standard regexp,  `egrep` or `grep -e` or `sed -E` use extended regexp, and the python code in the question uses PCRE, (perl common regular expression) GNU grep can use PCRE with `-P` option.

Comment: @FelipeBuccioni actually that should be `egrep` or `grep -E` or `sed -r`

Comment: For a single(first) match, append ` | head -1` (without backticks), as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14093511/3610458) to another question.

Comment: @SensorSmith Some `sed` implementations use `-r`, others use `-E`; still others don't have an option to change the regex dialect.

Comment: `grep` has `-m 1` to stop after the first match.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Finally a simple and elegant solution than `grep` / `awk` / `sed`

Comment: This doesn't handle multiple lines though.

Comment: @MattSt How so? If there are multiple matches (even within a single line; but definitely also across multiple lines), they will each be printed on its own output line.

Answer (score 8):

Try this instead:

```
echo "This is 02G05 a test string 20-Jul-2012" | sed 's/.* \([0-9]\+G[0-9]\+\) .*/\1/'
```

But note, if there is two pattern on one line, it will prints the 2nd.

Comment: Or more generally the last one if there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 6):

`sed` doesn't recognize `\d`, use `[[:digit:]]` instead. You will also need to escape the `+` or use the `-r` switch (`-E` on OS X).

Note that `[0-9]` works as well for Arabic-Hindu numerals.

Comment: I tried `sed  -n '/[0-9]\+G[0-9]\+/p'`. Now it just prints the whole string

Comment: @Noob: You will need to use substitution to [exclude the parts you don't want to print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777579/sed-group-capturing/2778096#2778096).

Answer (score 1):

We can use sed -En to simplify the regular expression, where:

```
n: suppress automatic printing of pattern space
E: use extended regular expressions in the script
```

```
$ echo "This is 02G05 a test string 20-Jul-2012" | sed -En 's/.*([0-9][0-9]+G[0-9]+).*/\1/p'

02G05
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [rextract](https://github.com/kata198/rextract). It will let you extract text using a regular expression and reformat it.

Example:

```
$ echo "This is 02G05 a test string 20-Jul-2012" | ./rextract '([\d]+G[\d]+)' '${1}'

2G05
```

Comment: If this uses standard regex, the square brackets around `\d` are completely superfluous.