# Grep only the first match and stop

Tags: grep

I'm searching a directory recursively using grep with the following arguments hoping to only return the first match. Unfortunately, it returns more than one -- in-fact two the last time I looked. It seems like I have too many arguments, especially without getting the  desired outcome. :-/

```
# grep -o -a -m 1 -h -r "Pulsanti Operietur" /path/to/directory
```

returns:

```
Pulsanti Operietur
Pulsanti Operietur
```

Maybe grep isn't the best way to do this? You tell me, thanks very much.

Answer (score 809):

`-m 1` means return the first match in any given file. But it will still continue to search in other files. Also, if there are two or more matched in the same line, all of them will be displayed.

#### You can use `head -1` to solve this problem:

```bash
grep -o -a -m 1 -h -r "Pulsanti Operietur" /path/to/dir | head -1
```

#### explanation of each grep option:

```
-o, --only-matching, print only the matched part of the line (instead of the entire line)
-a, --text, process a binary file as if it were text
-m 1, --max-count, stop reading a file after 1 matching line
-h, --no-filename, suppress the prefixing of file names on output
-r, --recursive, read all files under a directory recursively
```

Comment: awesome! thank you. btw - are all those other arguments necessary that I have in the command? and what if I can't pipe it by chance (just in case).

Comment: I don't think they are necessary (except for `-r` obviously), but they should not hurt (I would not use `-a` though)

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  My pattern was found twice on the same line and `grep -m 1` returned both instances because of this. `|head -1` solved it!

Comment: Does `head` short circuit once the first match is found?

Comment: @Chris_Rands the exact behavior depends on the shell that you are running in.  head will exit as soon as it encounters the first line.  grep will exit the next time it tries to write after head has exited.  Some shells will wait until all elements of a pipeline finish, some will cause the entire pipe to shutdown as soon as the last program in the pipe exits.

Comment: `head` is useless if the first hit is a very, very long line (as in a SQL dump or sim). Any other way to cope with that specific situation?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt: you can use `fold` as a filter to wrap long lines.

Comment: Question was first not first from result!

Comment: @3Qn, I don't understand your comment: `first not first from result`. This answer prints first match in any file and stops. What else did you expect?

Comment: What about if you want to use the `-B` or `-A` options to display additional context? Then piping through `head -n1` will only display the first line.

Answer (score 50):

You can pipe `grep` result to `head` in conjunction with **stdbuf**.

Note, that in order to ensure stopping after Nth match, you need to using `stdbuf` to make sure `grep` don't buffer its output:

```bash
stdbuf -oL grep -rl 'pattern' * | head -n1
stdbuf -oL grep -o -a -m 1 -h -r "Pulsanti Operietur" /path/to/dir | head -n1
stdbuf -oL grep -nH -m 1 -R "django.conf.urls.defaults" * | head -n1
```

As soon as `head` consumes 1 line, it terminated and `grep` will receive `SIGPIPE` because it still output something to pipe while `head` was gone.

This assumed that no file names contain newline.

Comment: I'm trying to adopt this solution to search in a large number of archive files with `xargs`: `find . -name '*.gz' | xargs -I '{}' stdbuf -oL zgrep -al 'pattern' {} | head -n 1`. This, however, does not terminate on the first match. Any advice?

Comment: Wouldn't `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option prevent buffer overhead without calling an additional utility?

Answer (score 36):

For anyone who lands here, as I did, perplexed as to why `--max-count` didn't seem to be working when acting on `stdin`...

**TL;DR** - `--max-count n` does *NOT* stop after finding `n` matches, it stops after finding all matches *on `n` lines*.

(And `stdin`, even if it's only a string, counts as one line.)

This is true despite the fact that, in `zsh 5.8`, at least, `man grep` describes the option this way:

```
-m num, --max-count=num
        Stop reading the file after num matches.
```

**Longer Explanation**

In my case, I was trying to grab just the first part of a relative path (`some` in the example below):

```bash
> echo "some/path/here" | grep -E -o -m 1 '[^\/]+'
```

and was quite confused when it gave me back

```
some
path
here
```

Thanks to the comment from @harperville above, I finally figured out: It's not about the *output*, it's about the *input*.

Indeed, when I tried

```bash
> echo "some/path/here \n another/path/there" | grep -E -o -m 1 '[^\/]+'
```

I got the same result as above (i.e., only the parts before the `\n` in this second example).

**Notes**

For those who are less familiar with `grep`:

- `-E` (`--extended-regexp`) tells it to use "extended" regular expressions, i.e., the ones you're used to from most other programming languages. The differences between "extended" and "basic" aren't big - it's just about which characters you need to escape in your regex - but as someone who's primarily a TS and Python developer, I always use `-E` because that way I never have to think about it. (Pro-tip: Add `alias grep="grep -E"` to your `.zshrc` and you'll never have to worry about it again!)
- `-o` (`--only-matching`) tells it to only print the matches, rather than each line on which it found a match.
- `-m n` (`--max-count n`) restricts it to returning matches from `n` lines. (If you've read this far you clearly already know that, though! )

Answer (score 24):

My grep-a-like program [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com) has a `-1` option that stops at the first match found anywhere.  It supports the `-m 1` that @mvp refers to as well.  I put it in there because if I'm searching a big tree of source code to find something that I know exists in only one file, it's unnecessary to find it and have to hit Ctrl-C.

Comment: so you would say that ack is faster than grep? I'm really concerned with the speed factor also.

Comment: ack can be faster than grep, depending on what it is you're searching.  Please note that ack is about searching source code.  If you're looking to search general files, it is less good at that, at least in ack 1.x.  Go read about ack and see if maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: I've been using Ack for a long while but recently switched to [The silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) which I find to be faster the Ack

Comment: I believe this should be the only answer because the OP said he wanted it done with grep, but the other answer uses head (both work of course) but there are some embedded/self created environments with minimal tools where grep is common and tail/head is not.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `ag` might be fast, but it _does not_ have the `-1` option which is useful in this case

Answer (score 19):

You can use below command if you want to print entire line and file name if the occurrence of particular word in current directory you are searching.

```bash
grep -m 1 -r "Not caching" * | head -1
```

Comment: `grep -m 1 string` worked for my purposes. This was by far the best answer for me.

Answer (score 6):

Reading the grep manual (man grep) this is the minimum command to find first match with Extended regexp. Example getting the ethernet name that in my laptop is NOT eth0!

```bash
$ ifconfig | grep -E -o -m 1 "^[a-z0-9]+"
```

Explanation:
-E for extended regexp,
-o to return just the match itself,
-m 1 to look for only one match

Answer (score 1):

A single liner, using `find`:

```bash
find -type f -exec grep -lm1 "PATTERN" {} \; -a -quit
```

Comment: This is going to be *very* slow, as find will spawn copy of grep for every file found. `grep -r` works a lot faster - its only one copy that does directory traversals.

Comment: True; though find can be customized to only operate on filtered results, which can then make the operation much faster than a catch-all grep. Depends on the context.