# grep parameter to stop after first match?

Tags: regex, r

I'm processing a large file in R and I only need the first match of a specific regex, but `grep` is processing further, which of course takes time.

Is there any way to make it stop after first match?

Edit: it seems it's not grep but readLines that's slow. Reading 120MB file takes 20s... how on earth can fread from data.table read it in <2s and how can I do it as fast

Comment: You could wrap `grep` into a loop that has explicit stopping constraints. Would that be slower?

Comment: Can you show us a sample benchmark test?  I am running a regular expression on both length-1 and length-40,000 characters, and the speed difference is  about 1-2%.

Comment: Also, how are you processing the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093452/grep-only-the-first-match-although-returning-more

Comment: @MarkLeiber: That question is about the `grep` command line utility, not the R function. This is specific to R.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code that uses `grep`?

Comment: Can you use while and break - compare the row number of first match with second match and break if row number of second number is bigger?

Answer (score 0):

according to [regular-expressions.info (see first paragraph)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) a recent version of **R** should support *regular expression subroutines* which can have quantifiers so in your case you should be able to do the following:

`(your-regex)(?1){1}`

- (your-regex-here) : capturing group of your regex
- (?1) : subroutine call to capturing group 1
- {1} match subroutine once