# grep - limit number of files read

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a directory with over 100,000 files. I want to know if the string `"str1"` exists as part of the content of any of these files.

The command: 
`grep -l 'str1' *` takes too long as it reads all of the files.

How can I ask `grep` to stop reading any further files if it finds a match? Any one-liner?

Note: I have tried `grep -l 'str1' * | head` but the command takes just as much time as the previous one.

Comment: Does the command work in a directory with small number of files?

Comment: Maybe, already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093452/grep-only-the-first-match-and-stop

Comment: `head -1` will do the trick

Comment: Maybe it's the glob that's very slow, if you have lots of files. How about `find path/to/directory/ -type f -exec grep -l 'str1' /dev/null {} +`?

Comment: Look at using `fgrep` in place of `grep` as you are searching for a fixed string.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the command you suggested returns multiple results.

Comment: @user2070775: the purpose of this comment was only to show that the main slowdown was because of the glob. Since you're using GNU `find`, you can use: `find path/to/directory/ -type f -exec grep -l 'str1' {} \; -quit`... but then since you have the GNU utilties, you might as well use Bill Karwin's answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naming 100,000 filenames in your command args is going to cause a problem. It probably exceeds the size of a shell command-line.

But you don't have to name all the files if you use the recursive option with just the name of the directory the files are in (which is `.` if you want to search files in the current directory):

```
grep -l -r 'str1' . | head -1
```

Comment: For a little extra oomph, I'd toss in `LC_ALL="C" grep -m1 -l -r 'str1' . | head -1`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, OP's question is tagged [tag:linux] so I think it's safe to assume they're using GNU grep.

Comment: fair enough... `;)`

Comment: `grep  -m 1 -l -e 'str1' * | head -1` print the error: `-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long`

Comment: @user2070775: that's why Bill said to use `grep -r` and not a glob (and that's why I suggested to use `find` in a comment).

Comment: It would be worth adding the `-F` arg to this solution.

Comment: @Zlemini, sure, depending on whether the pattern is a fixed string or a regular expression.

Comment: @bishop, I didn't include `-m 1` because it's redundant given that `-l` stops reading a file after the first match is found.

Comment: @BillKarwin Are you relying on SIGPIPE to kill `grep` after the first match?

Comment: @BillKarwinvit it is a great idea. I was wondering how you ensured `grep` was not continuing after the first match.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep -m 1` so that grep stops after finding the first match in a file.  It is extremely efficient for large text files.

```
grep -m 1 str1 * /dev/null | head -1
```

If there is a single file, then /dev/null above ensures that grep does print out the file name in the output.

If you want to stop after finding the first match in any file:

```
for file in *; do
  if grep -q -m 1 str1 "$file"; then
    echo "$file"
    break
  fi
done
```

The `for` loop also saves you from the `too many arguments` issue when you have a directory with a large number of files.

Comment: Very good. I was hoping to find a one liner, but these statements will do.

Comment: Note that OP is already using `-l` which makes `grep` stop after first match.

Comment: `for file in *` will never suffer from "too many arguments", it's a workaround for it. See, for example, here: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Comment: @BenjaminW. - thanks!  I wasn't aware of that.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @BenjaminW. but it's dead slow, and that's one of the OP's problems!

Comment: `for file in *` having special handling in the shell is a new (well, at some point) thing. I know various shells in the past (1990s) had many issues with errors and overflows when expanding items in shell builtins. I wouldn't rely on it, unless you **know** for a fact that the only shells you will ever use work that way.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Fair enough – but the `while` method with process substitution and `find` is, at least on my system, even slower. I just pointed out that I don't think it's necessary to address "Argument list too long" in a for loop (and the comment by @ZanLynx taught me that that's not always true).