# Unable to extract specific value of json file using sed in shell script

Tags: json, shell, sed, jq

I am using sed command for extracting a value which I get from the output after doing curl. Below is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
release=$(curl -H "Authorization:token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/tags/v1.0.0)
id=$(echo "$release" |sed -n -e 's/"id":\\ \\([0-9]\\+\\),/\\1/p' | head -n 1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g')
echo $id
```

The output I got after curl is a json file. Below is the output

```
{
 "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/v1.0.0",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello- 
   World/releases/1/assets",
   "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello- 
  World/releases/1/assets{?name,label}",
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello- 
  World/tarball/v1.0.0",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello- 
 World/zipball/v1.0.0",
 "id": 1234332,
  "node_id": "MDc6UmVsZWFzZTE=",
  "tag_name": "v1.0.0",
  "target_commitish": "master",
  "name": "v1.0.0",
  "body": "Description of the release",
  "draft": false,
  "prerelease": false,
  "created_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
  "published_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
  "author": {
   "login": "octocat",
   "id": 1353322,
   "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
   "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
   "gravatar_id": "",
   "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
   "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
   "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
   "following_url": 
   "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
   "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
   "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner} 
   {/repo}",
   "subscriptions_url": 
   "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
   "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
     "received_events_url": 
   "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
   "type": "User",
   "site_admin": false
   },
  "assets": [
   {
   "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello- 
   World/releases/assets/1",
  "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello- 
  World/releases/download/v1.0.0/example.zip",
   "id": 56432211,
   "node_id": "MDEyOlJlbGVhc2VBc3NldDE=",
   "name": "example.zip",
   "label": "short description",
   "state": "uploaded",
   "content_type": "application/zip",
   "size": 1024,
   "download_count": 42,
   "created_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
   "updated_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
   "uploader": {
     "login": "octocat",
     "id": 5663322,
     "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
     "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
     "gravatar_id": "",
     "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
     "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
     "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
     "following_url": 
     "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
     "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
     "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner} 
    {/repo}",
     "subscriptions_url": 
     "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
     "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
     "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
     "events_url": 
     "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
     "received_events_url": 
     "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
     "type": "User",
     "site_admin": false
   }
 }
 ]
}
```

The sed command I posted above must work as it was working for another curl commands.

There are multiple occurrence of the `id` value but I want the value of the first `ID` to be stored in the `id` variable which is `"id": 1234332`

But as output I am getting nothing.

Need help on this.

Comment: removed the -i command.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use double quotes instead of single ones unless you want anything in the quoted string to be expanded,
2. Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) for parsing JSON values, sed is a line-oriented tool and can't parse JSON syntax-wise.

E.g:

```
id=$(curl -H 'Authorization:token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/tags/v1.0.0' |
  jq -r '.id')
echo "$id"
```

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the sed command and it worked.

The double backslashes `\\` where escaping the command so I changed it to single 
backslash `\`
Below is the modified shell script.

```
release=$(curl -H "Authorization:token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/tags/v1.0.0)
id=$(echo "$release" | sed -n -e 's/"id":\ \([0-9]\+\),/\1/p' | head -n 1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g')
echo $id
```

Comment: The pipeline can probably be reduced to a single `sed` script. You can often get rid of `head` by changing your `sed` script to simply exit immediately as soon as it prints something. But I have not looked into this in more detail; as the competing answer suggests, you really don't want to use `sed` for this.

Answer (score 0):

The double backslashes match a literal backslash, that is why your code did not work.

You may try this grep:

```
id=$(grep -o -m 1 '"id": [0-9]\{1,\},' <<< "$release" | sed 's/"id": //' | sed 's/,//')
```

`-m 1` will get the first occurrence only (check [Grep only the first match and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093452/grep-only-the-first-match-and-stop)), `-o` will get the regex match text - `"id":` + 1 or mor digits and a comma, and `sed 's/"id": //' | sed 's/,//'` will remove `"id":` and the comma from the return text.