# too many arguents using []

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write an script to impose a static ip depending on the wi-fi. The problem comes when I try to execute the following expression, the output tells me that I have too many arguments.

```
[ $(cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf | grep 'interface wlan0') = 'interface wlan0' ]
```

Whereas checking this expression it gives the desired output.

```
[ $(iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep  'ESSID:"Wi-Fi 61"') = 'ESSID:"Wi-Fi 61"' ]
```

Could anyone tell me why the first expression does not works and the second works because to my understanding they have a similar structure.

Comment: The first grep probably outputs multiple lines. To fix the immediate error you could put your `$(subshells)` inside double-quotes, but the comparison would fail. Instead you can rely on the result code of `grep`: `if grep 'interface wlan0' /etc/dhcpd.conf; then ...`

Comment: Why wouldnt you just do `if grep -q pattern file` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> too many arguments

Just as the error says, you are supplying too many arguments.

`[ arg1 = arg2 ]`, the structure should be somewhat like this. Although, `$(cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf | grep 'interface wlan0')` should have produced multiline or multiword output due to which you get that error.

To avoid that error, you can simply enclose the result of the command in quotes which will make the complete result a single argument.

```
[ "$(cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf | grep 'interface wlan0')" = 'interface wlan0' ]
```

Although I think you are looking to get just the first match of `grep`. 
[Grep only the first match and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093452/grep-only-the-first-match-and-stop) should probably help you in that case.

Comment: In my case ```$(cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf | grep 'interface wlan0')``` does not output multiple lines, indeed, it outputs just one line.

Comment: @SergioPrieto: Right, but there is a space in the middle of that line. Bash applies *word splitting* to the result of `$(...)`; for example, something like `[ $(echo foo = foo) ]` is equivalent to `[ foo = foo ]`.

Comment: That is true, thanks @ruakh. I did not recall that.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Mihir explains what is going on.  And an alternate solution I find cleaner is to use the return code of your grep command as the if conditional.  If the return is 0 it evaluate too true.  If the value is anything else it false

So you don't get the output from the grep use the `-q` option.

```
if grep -q 'interface wlan0' /etc/dhcpcd.conf
then 
    # Do something
fi
if iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep -q 'ESSID:"Wi-Fi 61"'
then
    # Do something
fi
```