# Is there a way to abort a piped shell command?

Tags: grep, sh, tar

With this command:

```
$ tar -ztf /tmp/z.txz | grep -m 1 '/packagesite.txz$'
2.2.0/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/packagesite.txz
```

The result comes very quickly (less than 1 second) but then it continues to run for 10-15 more useless seconds. [I found out about `-m` here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14093452/1571426), but it did not help. It would be very nice if I could get it to abort immediately after finding the match. Is there any way? FYI must work in `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Did you append the head -1?  tar -ztf /tmp/z.txz | grep -m 1 '/packagesite.txz$' | head -1

Comment: @WaltDe - makes no difference with or without `| head -1`

Answer (score 2):

Nothing so far posted was effective, But I noticed something interesting in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62883/56075):

> `find . ... -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1"; kill "$PPID"' sh {} \;`

and more info about pipelines and process groups in [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1261201):

> If `pid` equals `0`, then `sig` is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process.

So I started playing around and lo and behold, it actually worked:

```
$ time tar -ztf /tmp/z.txz | grep -m1 '/packagesite\.txz$'
2.2.0/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/packagesite.txz
53.866 real, 3.947 user, 5.119 sys
$
$ time tar -ztf /tmp/z.txz | ( grep -m1 '/packagesite\.txz$' ; kill 0 )
2.2.0/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/packagesite.txz
Terminated
0.008 real, 0.003 user, 0.004 sys
```

At first I was worried about the "Terminated" text coming out, but it is not on stdout so it won't get in the way:

```
$ tar -ztf /tmp/z.txz | ( grep -m1 '/packagesite\.txz$' ; kill 0 ) > z.out
Terminated
$ cat z.out
2.2.0/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/packagesite.txz
```

**EDIT:**

I do note, however, that this solution messes up the status code, e.g.:

```
$ tar -ztf /home/mrengert/tmp/z.txz | ( grep -m1 '/packagesite\.txz$' ; kill 0 )
2.2.0/FreeBSD:11:amd64/latest/packagesite.txz
Terminated
$ echo $?
143
```

Also - if you use it in a script you have to be careful about preventing signal propagation, otherwise it will terminate the script. You need to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap '' SIGTERM  # ignore signal temporarily
( trap - SIGTERM ; tar -ztf z.txz | ( grep -m1 '/packagesite\.txz$' ; kill 0 ) )
trap - SIGTERM   # restore signal handling
```

Comment: If you wrap as `(cmd) || true`, you'll get status code 0 at the end.

Comment: @kenorb - ... yes, but then if there is a REAL problem (e.g. tar getting a bad archive), you miss it.  I think I will just check explicitly for `[ $? -ne 0 -a $? -ne 143 ]` BTW, 143 is 128 + (whatever kill code, e.g. SIGTERM = 15).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to buffering. Here's an easier way to repro.

```
perl -le 'for (1..1000) { print "$_"; sleep 1 }' | grep -m 1 4
```

Nothing seems to happen, even though you can verify by taking out the `grep` that the fourth line of output is a match.

Turning off buffering from Perl solves the immediate problem:

```
perl -le '$| = 1; for (1..1000) { print "$_"; sleep 1 }' | grep -m 1 4
4
```

(and the output comes after 4 seconds, predictably).

There are no completely portable solutions to this; see if you have one of the utilities described at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009 or perhaps make sure `tar` produces enough output that you can rely on the output buffer filling up.

Comment: I tried using `stdbuf -oL` as indicated in the link you provided (and in many other ways) and it made no difference. I found something that works - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your file is large or your storage device is slow. Grep is going to filter the result and stop reading the pipe, but it won't kill the piped command.

If you know that the results are shown after 1 second, as for the workaround you can use `timeout` to kill the shell command after that time. For example:

```
timeout 1 tar -ztf /tmp/z.txz | grep -m1 '/packagesite.txz$'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't be sure how long it will take. I found something that works though - see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It doesn't work as expected, as per my finding and referring `grep` `man` pages it works with only with files.

below is a snippet from the `man` page:

> -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>
> Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the input is
> standard  input  from  a regular file, and NUM matching lines are
> output, grep ensures that the standard input is positioned to just
> after the last  matching  line  before  exiting,  regardless  of  the
> presence  of trailing context lines.  This enables a calling process
> to resume a search. When grep stops after NUM matching lines, it
> outputs any trailing context  lines.   When the  -c  or  --count
> option is also used, grep does not output a count greater than NUM.
> When the -v or --invert-match option is also used, grep stops after
> outputting NUM  non- matching lines.