# Storing result of "tail -f | grep" into a variable

Tags: bash

I am storing a line in a file named `linge.org`.  When I use the `tail` command directly, I get the match, but I cannot store the result in the variable `val`.  I would like to capture the first matched line from the end and return it to `val`.

```
 echo "zblank: Joe" > linge.org
 tail -f linge.org | grep "zblank"
 val=$( tail -f linge.org | grep "zblank" )
```

Comment: The `-f` will prevent `tail` from exiting, so there's nothing to capture. So make it `val=$( tail linge.org | grep "zblank" )`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  Would like to capture the first match from the end of the file, but I think that my implementation will get all matches.

Comment: What do you mean by "from the end"? If you read forward from the end, there's nothing there.

Comment: `tail -f` finds new contents, but it does that by continuing to run indefinitely. You want your program to _finish_, so you can't use `tail -f`.

Comment: Or do you just mean you want to search from the end to the front? That's a different, easier question -- `tail` is the wrong tool, but there's a correct one (`tac`, IIRC?)

Comment: I want to return tho last matched line in the file that starts with `zblank`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html):

> -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
>
> output appended data as the file grows;
> an absent option argument means 'descriptor'

---

The `-f` will prevent `tail` from competing. If you paste your command into your console, it will not finish.

Remove the `-f` so `tail` will finish as expected (you can use `-n` to increase the number of lines shown)

```
bash-3.2$ echo "zblank: Joe" > linge.org
bash-3.2$ val=$( tail linge.org | grep "zblank" )
bash-3.2$ echo "$val"
zblank: Joe
bash-3.2$
```

---

Edit based on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122092/storing-result-of-grep-into-a-variable/69122195#comment122167004_69122092)

> Would like to capture the first match from the end of the file, but I think that my implementation will get all matches

To get the desired output, first reverse the file ([`tac`](https://ss64.com/bash/tac.html)), then capture the [first match by using `head`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093452/grep-only-the-first-match-and-stop)

Example output from my local bash terminal:

```
bash-3.2$ cat linge.org
zblank: line 1
zblank: line 2
zblank: line 3
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ val=$( tac linge.org | grep "zblank" | head -n1  )
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ echo $val
zblank: line 3
bash-3.2$
```