# How can I use sed to extract a single value in command line?

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to extract information from an environment variable in my Travis-CI config so I'm looking for a 1-line linux command that'll do this based on my regex.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
  - MAJOR_VERSION=`sed -i 's/[v?]((([\d]+)\.[\d]+)\.[\d]+)/$1/g' <<< ${TRAVIS_TAG}`
  - MINOR_VERSION=`sed -i 's/[v?]((([\d]+)\.[\d]+)\.[\d]+)/$1.$2/g' <<< ${TRAVIS_TAG}`
  - PATCH_VERSION=`sed -i 's/[v?]((([\d]+)\.[\d]+)\.[\d]+)/$1.$2.$./g' <<< ${TRAVIS_TAG}`
```

It appears `sed` expects a file or files because I get the error `sed: no input files`, not a string.  How can I get it to expect a string?

My objective is to take a semantic version tag (e.g. - `v12.34.56` or `12.34.56` and extract the version numbers.

Comment: Using `-i` is a mistake in general.   Using it when processing a non-regular file is a disaster.

Comment: Based on what I have read \d might not be supported by your sed. Try using [0-9] instead. egrep might be a better option than sed. Check this page to learn more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568859/how-to-extract-text-from-a-string-using-sed

Comment: And to explicitly answer the question, just stop using `-i` and sed will read from stdin.

Comment: since you are extracting information from a string, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion might be better choice (assuming bash shell or similar) .. adding sample  content of string and expected output would help

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks, I'm looking into that... I've added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you are using sed at all.  If TRAVIS_TAG contains nothing but a string of the form "xx.xx.xx", then you would just read it:

```
IFS=. read MAJOR_VERSION MINOR_VERSION PATCH_VERSION <<< "$TRAVIS_TAG"
```

if you're worried about a possible leading `v` that you want to discard:

```
IFS=. read MAJOR_VERSION MINOR_VERSION PATCH_VERSION <<< "${TRAVIS_TAG#v}"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed