# output of sed gives strange result when using capture groups

Tags: bash, sed

I'm doing the following command in a bash:

```
echo -e 'UNUSED\nURL: ^/tags/0.0.0/abcd' | sed -rn 's#^URL: \^/tags/([^/]+)/#\1#p'
```

I think this should output only the matching lines and the content of the capture group. So I'm expecting `0.0.0` as the result. But I'm getting `0.0.0abcd`

Why contains the capture group parts from the left and the right side of the `/`? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568859/how-to-extract-text-from-a-string-using-sed/11568930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo -e 'UNUSED\nURL: ^/tags/0.0.0/abcd' |
sed -rn 's#^URL: \^/tags/([^/]+)/#\1#p'
```

`echo` outputs two lines:

```
UNUSED
URL: ^/tags/0.0.0/abcd
```

The regular expression given to `sed` does not match the first line, so this line is not printed. The regular expression *matches* the second line, so `URL: ^/tags/0.0.0/` is replaced with `0.0.0`; only the matched part of the line is replaced, so `abcd` is passed unchanged.

To obtain the desired output you must also match `abcd`, for example with

```
sed -rn 's#^URL: \^/tags/([^/]+)/.*#\1#p'
```

where the `.*` eats all characters to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
echo -e 'UNUSED\nURL: ^/tags/0.0.0/abcd'  | awk -F/ 'index($0, "^/tags/"){print $3}'

0.0.0
```

This `awk` command uses `/` as field delimiter and prints 3rd column when there `^/tags/` text in input.

Alternatively, you can use `gnu grep`:

```
echo -e 'UNUSED\nURL: ^/tags/0.0.0/abcd' | grep -oP '^URL: \^/tags/\K([^/]+)'

0.0.0
```

Or this `sed`:

```
echo -e 'UNUSED\nURL: ^/tags/0.0.0/abcd' | sed -nE 's~^URL: \^/tags/([^/]+).*~\1~p'

0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This sed catch your desired output.

```
echo -e 'UNUSED\nURL: ^/tags/0.0.0/abcd' | sed -E '/URL/!d;s#.*/(.*)/[^/]*#\1#'
```