# sed is not changing the string

Tags: unix, sed, sh

I have 3 files:

```
File1: &VAR1='1111';
File2: &VAR2 = '2222';
File3: &VAR1 = 1111
```

I want to change that for example with &NEWVAR = 'NEW';

So I have the following script:

```
A="\&VAR1\s*\=\s*'*[1]{4}'*"
for f in /u/123456/*; do
    if grep -qE $A $f; then
        sed 's/$LAREXP/$LACADE/g' $f
    fi
done
```

Grep tells me there are coincidence en File1 and File3, wich is correct, but the sed command is no replacing the old string with the new one in those files. It shows on screen the content of the files but there's no replace.

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards,

Comment: Try `sed -i`, this edits the file in place instead of printing the result onto the terminal

Comment: What are the dollar signs in the sed command for? If they're for the end of string then the pattern will never match, and if they're meant to be shell variables then they won't be expanded since they're within single quotes.

Comment: Moreover, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: Finally, neither `sed` nor `grep` commonly support PCRE regex like `\s`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568859/how-to-extract-text-from-a-string-using-sed/11568930#11568930

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `sed -i` to change the files in-place.

`sed` is a *Stream EDitor* and thus, by default, it edits data it reads and then writes it to stdout. Passing `-i` tells `sed` to write the changes back to the file given on the command line.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathon

I used -i and the text stoped showing on screen, but the text hasnt changed. In fact, the 2 files have been edited, but sed did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to accomplish.  The *obvious* errors are fixed in the following annotated code.

```
# The regex is probably also incorrect; see blowe
A="\&VAR1\s*\=\s*'*[1]{4}'*"
for f in /u/123456/*; do
    # Add quotes around regex and filename
    if grep -qE "$A" "$f"; then
        # single quotes will not work; use doubles
        # add -i option for in-place editing
        # again, add duoble quotes around filename
        sed -i "s/$LAREXP/$LACADE/g" "$f"
    fi
done
```

The regex will certainly not work in `sed` and probably not in `grep` either.  There are many different regex dialects and you have used constructs from Perl/Python regex which are not usually supported by older tools.  *Perhaps* you mean

```
A="\\\\&VAR[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*'*1111'*"
```

which should work in both POSIX `grep` and POSIX `sed`. Some platforms support `sed -E` or `sed -r` to use something called POSIX Extended Regular Expressions ... but really this is too speculative without any indications of what the regex is supposed to match.

A common workaround is to use Perl.

```
perl -pi -e "s/$LAREXP/$LACADE/g" /u/123456/*
```

depending also on what's in `LAREXP` and `LACADE`.