# How to use sed to extract the specific substring?

Tags: bash, sed

```
div class="panel-body" id="current-conditions-body">
    <!-- Graphic and temperatures -->
    <div id="current_conditions-summary" class="pull-left" >
                    <img src="newimages/large/sct.png" alt="" class="pull-left" />
                    <p class="myforecast-current">Partly Cloudy</p>
        <p class="myforecast-current-lrg">64&deg;F</p>
        <p class="myforecast-current-sm">18&deg;C</p>
```

I try to extract the "64" in line 6, I was thinking to use `awk '/<p class="myforecast-current-lrg">/{print}'`, but this only gave me the full line. Then I think I need to use `sed`, but i don't know how to use `sed`.

Comment: Use a HTML parser.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please do not post images of text in questions.  Just copy paste and format it as code (`{}` icon in the editor).

Comment: Bro, you can find the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568859/how-to-extract-text-from-a-string-using-sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- input is nicely formatted as per the sample provided by OP so we can use some 'simple' pattern matching

Modifying OP's current `awk` code:

```
# use split() function to break line using dual delimiters ">" and "&"; print 2nd array entry

awk '/<p class="myforecast-current-lrg">/{ n=split($0,arr,"[>&]");print arr[2]}'

# define dual input field delimiter as ">" and "&"; print 2nd field in line that matches search string

awk -F'[>&]' ' /<p class="myforecast-current-lrg">/{print $2}'
```

Both of these generate:

```
64
```

---

One `sed` idea:

```
sed -En 's/.*<p class="myforecast-current-lrg">([^&]+)&deg.*/\1/p'
```

This generates:

```
64
```